# Plot of a function given by an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions, mathematica

I want to plot the following integral as a function of $x$ but Mathematica fails to draw it even using the numerical integration.
$$f(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^4e^{-e^{4 u} n^2 \pi }\right)   (e^{9 u}\text{Cosh}(xu)) \, du$$
How should I plot it, say on some finite interval?

EDIT: Here is what I tried for numerical plot: $$ g[u\_]=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } e^{-e^{4 u} n^2 \pi } \left(e^{9 u} n^4 \right)*(Cosh[x*u]){FunctionExpand}\text{\\\\}$$

$$f[x\_]:=({NIntegrate}[g[u],\{u,0,10\}]) $$
$$Plot[f[x], \{x, 1, 5\}] $$ .
The output I get is:[image: Output]

Comment: Can you post your MMA code?

Comment: Here is what I tried for numerical plot: $$ g[u\_]=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } e^{-e^{4 u} n^2 \pi } \left(e^{9 u} n^4 \right)*(Cosh[x*u]){FunctionExpand}\text{\\\\}$$

$$f[x\_]:=({NIntegrate}[g[u],\{u,0,10\}]) $$
$$Plot[f[x], \{x, 1, 5\}] $$ .

Comment: The $n$ summation quickly drops off after a few terms so you can approximate. In any case I believe you can do the integration which comes out as some exponential integral functions.

Comment: @user121049 Any starting point to start from?

Comment: Get Mathematica to do the integral exactly for a given value of $n$. Check that it converges for the values of x you are interested in.Then look at the first few terms in the sum for various values of $x$ to see how many you will need.

Comment: @Moo, How to write a code here. Is there any command like I use \lstlistings in Latex to insert codes 
with nice formatting? Actuallly, I am new relatively new here.

Comment: @user121049 I plotted the exact integral for $n=10$. I got the plot! Also, the value of summation for $u=1$ at  $n=10$ and at $n=\infty$ is same as $3.21792\times 10^-75$. This shows sum really falls just after few terms. But is my plot still close to the reality by taking $n=10$?

Comment: As far as I can se the first exponential term will always kill off anything that threatens to get nasty. When you say $n=10$,  I assume you mean the first 10 terms. If so then you are done.

Comment: Yes, I mean first $n$ terms. I checked for $n=10$, then for $n=20$. The plot is same. Thanks, it worked.